# Participle Clause as Attribute or Other Than This?

Tags: grammar

In the below sentence, does the participle clause "coming together to find their love for each other" work as attribute for "two broken people" or other than this?

> It (Swan Lake) is the journey of two broken people coming together to find their love for each other.

Comment: Attribute? Yes, and *coming together to find love* would say the same thing.

Comment: There are two possibilities: [1] "two broken people coming together ..." is a clause functioning as complement of the preposition "of", where "two broken people" is subject and the VP "coming together ..." is predicate. [2] "two broken people coming together" is an NP with "people" as head, modified by the gerund-participial clause "coming together ...". The latter is the semantic equivalent of "two broken people who come together ...".

Comment: @BillJ Could it be "coming together to find their love for each other" as an attribute in whole for "two broken people"?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an attributive". Are you talking about attributive grammar?